# Using async await on .then function with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing some functional testing with mocha. I stored my functions name, parameters and sucess message in local JSON file. I am checking my database response with local JSON response.
I'm using .then and .catch everywhere. I am looking to clean up a code with async await. How I can use async await here?

```js
it('Check Authentication', (done) => {
    readFileData('checkAuth').then(({ params, message}) => {
      login.checkAuth({ ...params })
        .then((result) => {
          assert(result.message === message);
          done();
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err));
    });
});
```

Comment: if you are not sure how to convert your example, which is very trivial, to `async`/`await`, its probably best to go and do some reading on the `async` / `await` syntax, and all will be clear for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Haven't tested it tho. Basically instead of `.then()` you just `await` the call. Note that there is `async` before `(done)` callback. `.catch()` can be caught with `try/catch` block.

```
it('Check Authentication', async (done) => {
       let response = await readFileData('checkAuth');
       try {
         let message = await login.checkAuth({ ...response.params }); // or w/e the response is
         // assert the message
       } catch (e) {
          // do something with the error
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- Changed callback function to `async` to use `await
- Wrapped all `await` calls in `try-catch` block to handle errors
- Used `const` for `params`, `message` and `result` variables but if you are going to reassign values later in the code you can use `let` instead.
- `done()` will be async call. Add `await` in front of that if you need that too to be sync call

```js
it('Check Authentication', async (done) => {
    try {
        const { params, message } = await readFileData('checkAuth');
        const result = await login.checkAuth({ ...params });
        assert(result.message === message);
        done();
    } catch (err) {
        done(err);
    }
});
```